# Error: blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff) Shopify

Tags: node.js, express, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api-node

```
const scriptRequestHeaders = {
    'X-Shopify-Access-Token': accessToken,
    'Content-Type': 'text/javascript',
     };

  const script_tag = {
    "script_tag": {
      "event": "onload",
      "src": "some link here from google drive or github"
    }
  }
```

I am using above code to use script_tags api but I am getting blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff) and cannot get past it. Can someone please provide me a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get around the header as it is being set the server which is sending you the resource. You need to use a URL that strictly returns a js file. There is a mismatch in the content type being requested by the browser and returned by the URL and as a result, browsers won't allow the resource to load.

More information about Mime Sniffing - https://www.keycdn.com/support/what-is-mime-sniffing

Comment: Thanks for the reply brother, I understand what you mean.